# Copy text to clipboard with MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I think the title says it all - is it possible to programmatically copy/paste some text to/from the windows clipboard using MapBasic?

I have found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/b7e30bd6dd3bd537/278d68843d6b3d43?hl=en) but it only discusses copying and as it's two years and 1.5 versions ago I'm wondering if there's a better/more native option.

Comment: What is the text you are trying to copy? For instance is it a attribute of an object or an object from a layout?

Comment: The result of WindowInfo(FrontWindow(), WIN_INFO_CLONEWINDOW). I want to have two instances of MapInfo open and easily copy a layout window between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the objects from the layout onto the clipboard you can do the following:

```
dim strLayWinName As String
strLayWinName = WindowInfo(FrontWindow(), 10) ' assuming layout window is front window
Select * From strLayWinNAme
Run Menu Command 203
```

You will then need to work out how to switch instances of MapInfo (or just open a new one). Then you need to set your layout window as the Front Window. Then run:

```
Run Menu Command 204
```